# c++ User defined conversion - implicit conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a question about user defined conversion.

```
class String {
    char* m_data;

public:
    String(): m_data(NULL) {}
    String(const char* cstr): m_data(new char[strlen(cstr)+1]) {
        strcpy(m_data, cstr);
    }
    ~String() {
        delete[] m_data;
    }
    String& operator=(const char* cstr) {
        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = new char[strlen(cstr)+1];
        strcpy(m_data, cstr);
        return *this;
    }
    operator const char*() const { 
        return m_data;
    }
};
```

While this works:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    String a;
    String b;
    a = "aaa";
    b = (const char *)a;
    return 0;
}
```

This does not:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    String a;
    String b;
    a = "aaa";
    b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

I get `double free or corruption` runtime error. Valgrind says something about invalid delete.

Why do I have to explicitly typecast it? I thought it would work this way with `explicit operator const char*()`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Long story short: assignment operator `String& operator=(const String& other)` is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to define [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator):

```
String& operator=(const String& other) {
    if(this != &other) {
        char* new_data = new char[strlen(other.m_data)+1];
        strcpy(new_data, other.m_data);
        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = new_data;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Because of that your compiler had to define "default" copy assignment operator, which simple assigns all fields of "other" to a current object:

```
String& operator=(const String& other) {
    m_data = other.m_data;
    return *this;
}
```

So you have two pointers to same `m_data` in `a` and `b` and on the exit from `main`, `delete[]` will be called twice.

Comment: Please add the checks to take care of self assignment, which should be a no op.

Comment: Have you checked that a copy assignment operator is generated when an assignment operator (not copy assignment) is defined.